# Лицензионное ПО embarcadero

Tags: delphi, лицензирование, interbase

1. На сайте Embarcadero [продается  INTERBASE XE3 SERVER](http://store.embarcadero.ru/catalog/rubric/29). Там указана цена сервера и количество пользователей. Что означает это количество пользователей? Т.е. я куплю сервер за 7000 и с базой сможет работать только один компьютер?
2. К примеру я пишу ПО для коммерческой организации на нелицензионной IDE (при этом нет никаких договоров, кроме словесных), то какие риски появляются у этой самой организации, при использовании данного ПО. И как поверочная комиссия сможет определить, является ли данное рукоделие нелицензионным.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Да, верно. В этом и смысл лицензий на пользователя. Возможно даже тут подразумевается не просто один пользователь (вообще), а кол-во одновременных подключений от разных пользователей = X. Т.е., скажем, из десяти пользователей, для которых заведены учетные записи, единомоментно может работать один. Но это все надо уточнять для каждого ПО.
2. Есть разные способы. Но в общем-то, если авторство ПО ясно, то, понятно, что автор должен был иметь лицензию на средства инструментальной разработки. К тому же компиляторы оставляют следы в исполняемом файле, как то: имя компьютера, время компиляции, пути к файлам и пр.